# EntityReference attribute is not always completely populated

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm-2011

Here's a LINQ to CRM query:

```
Contact crmContact = xrm.ContactSet.Where(x => x.ContactId == contactId).SingleOrDefault();
```

I've got an attribute, an `EntityReference`, as such:

```
crmContact.assigned_clinic;
```

As you know, an `EntityReference` contains these attributes:

```
- Id (the Guid of the entity that it refers to)
- LogicalName (what type of entity does this reference references to)
- Name (the 'Name' attribute of the entity that's being refered to)
```

For some reasons I cannot put my finger on, in certain circumstances, the `LogicalName` and `Name` attributes are populated correctly, sometimes, they are empty strings.

Any ideas to force a complete retrieval of that data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that was not long. I thought SingleOrDefault() retrieved everything, but apparently, you need to call ToList() for that to happen. I changed the query to:

```
Contact crmContact = xrm.ContactSet.Where(x => x.ContactId == contactId).ToList().SingleOrDefault();
```

And now all `EntityReference` attributes are being populated correctly. Sometimes I was doing so, sometimes not which explains the "not always completely populated" mystery.

Answer (score 1):

The technical reason is written on MSDN:

[EntityReference.Name Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.entityreference.name.aspx)

> This property can contain a value or null. This property is not
>   automatically populated unless the EntityReference object has been
>   retrieved from the server.